# Какой дистрибутив perl выбрать?

Tags: дистрибутив, perl

Варианты:

ActivePerl

Strawberry Perl

DWIM Perl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы уточняйте, что у Вас винда. Под линуксом подобных проблем не возникает.

- ActivePerl - известный старичек, начал бы с него. Подозреваю, что он хорош тем, что у него есть платная версия для большого "энтерпрайза".
- Strawberry Perl включает в себя MinGW и если у Вас есть пакеты с XS, то вроде должно компилировать без проблем (хотя специалисты всегда могут написать так код, что под виндой он никогда не будет работать).
- DWIM Perl - первый раз слышу о таком.

Хотя честно - я бы взял линукс и не переживал. Там нет этих проблем и практически во всех дистрибутивах (в том числе и FreeBSD) perl есть "изкоробки".